# How to disable crosshair in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

So far I've only successfully "removed" the crosshair of this game by increasing the size of "...crosshairrange" values of each weapon to 10000 using ME3Coalesced. The only thing left that I haven't able to find is the hit-indicator (the cross that appears in the middle of the screen  whenever you hit something). Anybody has an idea which value this thing is at?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just have to ask: Why?

Comment: Just the crosshair and hit marker or is the whole HUD ok? Binding a key to ShowHud will let you toggle all UI elements.

Comment: I bind a key to toggle the HUD on and off and it does hide everything. Only problem now is that I might miss a "view-event" from time to time since it hides those indicators as well.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable the hit markers in ME3.

Comment: The ShowHUD command does disable the hit-marker so it must be an element in the HUD. Problem is which one. I just cannot find it.